# calculating factorial in Python

Tags: python, syntax, integer, python-2.x

When calculating

```
math.factorial(100)
```

I get:

93326215443944152681699238856266700490715968264381621468592963895217599993229915608941463976156518286253697920827223758251185210916864000000000000000000000000L

Why is there an L at the end of the number?

Comment: Wow, I'm impressed that Python can do this!  May need to jump ship and become a Python person.

Comment: Python goes to eleventeen-kerjillion.

Comment: I heard it can also do imaginary numbers like thirty-twelve

Comment: What tutorial are you reading?  Please update the question with the title or a link.

Comment: @msw: Python 3 goes to 40 hundred kabillion.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does python add an 'L' on the end of the result of large exponents?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23741762/why-does-python-add-an-l-on-the-end-of-the-result-of-large-exponents)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

L means it's a `long` as opposed to an `int`. The reason you see it is that you are looking at the `repr` of the `long`

You can use

```
print math.factorial(100)
```

or

```
str(math.factorial(100))
```

if you just want the number

Answer (score 3):

The `L` means that it's a long integer

Comment: nopey. They are longs, not C longs but longs. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0237/

Answer (score 1):

I believe that you are working with a BigInt, which is known as `long` in Python - it expands and occupies a variable amount of RAM as needed. The name `long` can be confusing, as that means a specific number of bytes in a handful of popular languages of today. The following can help you get at the number of bytes it takes to store the object.

```
Python 2.6.2 (r262:71600, Aug 14 2009, 22:02:40) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5493)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 
>>> import sys
>>> a = 1
>>> sys.getsizeof(a)
12
>>> import math
>>> sys.getsizeof(math.factorial(100))
84
>>> sys.getsizeof(math.factorial(200))
182
>>>
```

Comment: Although informative, this isn't related to the question and I've seen people get downvoted (pettily, if I may opine) for less. You might want to delete this.

Comment: @msw, let's see what happens. It is not as if I care that much about my rep - it is just a number. If it goes down, I will throw in a popular answer fast enough and will more than make up for it.

Answer (score 0):

you could use the factorial calculator code...

```
def factorial (number):
    product=1;
    for i in range(number):
        product=product*(i+1)
    return product
```

I do not have Python, so I did not test out the code. I guarantee that this function will work.

Comment: Actually Eric's solution works, even though it is a bit long.  I am voting it up.  I don't know why someone voted it down.

Answer (score 0):

## Python factorial using for loop

```
def fact(n):
  if n<=1:
    print("Enter a positive no.")
  else:
    for i in range(n,1,-1):
      n = n*(i-1)
    return n
print(fact(int(input("Enter a number : "))))
```