# Why does python add an 'L' on the end of the result of large exponents?

Tags: python, python-2.x, exponent

If you've noticed, python adds an **L** on to the end of large exponent results like this:

```
>>> 25 ** 25
88817841970012523233890533447265625L
```

After doing some tests, I found that any number below 10 doesn't include the **L**. For example:

```
>>> 9 ** 9
387420489
```

This was strange, so, why does this happen, is there any method to prevent it? All help is appreciated!

Comment: Because on the C level, I believe that integer is of type `long`.

Comment: @Alex_Thornton What do you mean by __long__?

Comment: Ick, misfired, that wasn't the best dupe. Wasted my hammer there.

Comment: You look at the representation of the number. The number itself does not have a trailing `L`.

Comment: @AlexThornton: I would like to see you fit `88817841970012523233890533447265625` into a C long...

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_(computer_science)#Long_integer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why do integers in database row tuple have an 'L' suffix?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11764713)

Comment: @AlexThornton A long integer does not correspond to the `long` data type in C; rather it is an arbitrary precision integer implemented by Python.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Python supports arbitrary precision integers, meaning you're able to represent larger numbers than a normal 32 or 64 bit integer type. The `L` tells you when a literal is of this type and not a regular integer.

Note, that `L` only shows up in the interpreter output, it's just signifying the type. If you print that result instead:

```
>>> print(25 ** 25)
88817841970012523233890533447265625
```

The `L` doesn't get printed.

In Python 3, these types have been merged, so Python 3 outputs:

```
Python 3.4.0 (default, Apr 11 2014, 13:05:11) 
[GCC 4.8.2] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> 24 ** 24
1333735776850284124449081472843776
```

Comment: I know this is a small issue, but since ```print(25**25)``` is clearly Python 3, the ```L``` wouldn't show regardless.

Comment: The parens work fine in either version, but yes that is true.

Comment: @wnnmaw Why would `print(25**25)` be clearly Python 3?

Comment: @user189, because I didn't know ```print(x)``` was valid Python 2 :P  I assumed that meant it would be treated like a function, hence Python 3